# How to test developement environment work in cross devices to fix UI issues?

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, cross-platform, frontend

While I am working on projects in local environments..I have to test the project in cross platforms inorder to avoid the issues in production.

For example, I provided overflow property to a bootstrap modal..I tested it in browser emulators..It looks good.But, while testing on actual devices after pushing code to production..I found the overflow property didn't work.

Are there any applicatons to test the cross platform which provides entire IOS/Android environments?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Emulator, its good for Phonegap and Device related functionality testing.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc